# Activity doesn't start when calling it with startActivity

Tags: android, service

somehow my SetPasswordActivity doesn't start. I registered it in the manifest and call it the regular way:

```
final Intent intentSetPassword = new Intent(this, SetPasswordActivity.class);
switchPassword.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener()
    {
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked)
        {
            Log.d("Switch", "Is Checked: "+isChecked);
            if (isChecked){
                SharedPreferences sharedPreferencesPassword = getSharedPreferences("SETTINGS_PASSWORD", 0);
                boolean isPasswordSet = sharedPreferencesPassword.getBoolean("IS_PASSWORD_SET", false);
                Log.d("Password", "IsPasswordSet: "+isPasswordSet);
                if (!isPasswordSet){
                    Log.d("SetPasswordStarted", "true");
                    startService(intentSetPassword);
                }
                buttonSetPassword.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }else{
                buttonSetPassword.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
        }
    });
```

And here are my Logs:

```
D/Switch: Is Checked: true
D/Password: IsPasswordSet: false
D/SetPasswordStarted: true
V/AudioManager: playSoundEffect   effectType: 0
I/zygote64: Do full code cache collection, code=251KB, data=200KB
I/zygote64: After code cache collection, code=247KB, data=155KB
W/libEGL: EGLNativeWindowType 0x7a948b9010 disconnect failed
```

The code is running the if condition and writing the Log     D/SetPasswordStarted: true
but it doesn't start the Activity.
Could you help me?

Comment: Are you trying to start an Activity or a Service? What does SetPasswordActivity extend?

Comment: I want to start an activity. Sorry for the mistakes. I edited my question.

Comment: Can you post how you declared it in the Manifest, and what SetPasswordActivity extends?

Comment: if `SetPasswordActivity` is an `Activity` Try using `startActivity()` instead of `startService()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You try to start a service but not an activity on this line

```
startService(intentSetPassword);
```

You should change it to

```
startActivity(intentSetPassword);
```